# Extract the first number (with decimals) after a given symbol from a string with multiple numbers in R

Tags: r, regex, substring, decimal

I'm trying to get the numbers (including decimals) from a string.
My data is similar to this:

```
V <- c("7.20-<7.35","25-<32","60-<83e","40-<50","0.85-<1.15","80-<98","3.0-<3.4","NA","3.0-<3.4 (110)")
```

Where numbers are mixed with letters and symbols.
I need to extract the first number after the < symbol while keeping the index for the missing values.
My output would look like:

```
desired.output <- c(7.35, 32, 83, 50, 1.15, 98, 3.4, NA, 3.4)
```

I have tried:

```
resp <- as.numeric(unlist(regmatches(V,
                 gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]*",V))))
```

and

```
resp <-  sub(".*<(^[^-])", "\\1", V)
```

and another patterns in the sub function but nothing seems to work.

What do you suggest as best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
sub(".*<(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?).*", "\\1", V, perl=TRUE)
# => [1] "7.35" "32"   "83"   "50"   "1.15" "98"   "3.4"  "NA"   "3.4"
```

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/xE6QVw) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y0Bym1/1). Replace `\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?` with `\\d*\\.?\\d+` if you need to also get numbers like `.05`. Append `-?` before the first `\\d+` if you need to also get negative numbers.

*Details*:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `<` - a `<` char
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 1 (referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern): one or more digits followed with an optional sequence of a dot and one or more digits
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible

Comment: Thanks it works! Just a small question: if instead of a "<" I would have a "-" ,">" or both "->", can I use ".*-|>(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?).*" or "".*[:punct:](\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?).*"?

Comment: @AnaAntunes You can use `sub(".*[<>-](\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?).*", "\\1", V, perl=TRUE)`. And `sub(".*[[:punct:]](\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?).*", "\\1", V, perl=TRUE)` is also good.

Answer (score 0):

You could also specify the first numbers followed by `-<` and capture the second part with an optional decimal.

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?-<(\d+(?:\.\d+)?).*
```

The pattern matches:

- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `-<` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `)` Close group 1
- `.*` Match the rest of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z6ijZ6/1)

Then you can match the rest of the string that you don't want in the result, and replace with group 1.

```
V <- c("7.20-<7.35","25-<32","60-<83e","40-<50","0.85-<1.15","80-<98","3.0-<3.4","NA","3.0-<3.4 (110)")
sub("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?-<(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?).*", "\\1", V)
```

Output

```
[1] "7.35" "32"   "83"   "50"   "1.15" "98"   "3.4"  "NA"   "3.4"
```

---

Matching all variations of `-` `<` or `>`, you can use a character class listing all the allowed characters and repeat them 1 or more times:

```
sub("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?[<>-]+(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?).*", "\\1", V)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gElrrB/1)

Answer (score 0):

Using `str_extract` from `stringr` package in tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
V <- c("7.20-<7.35","25-<32","60-<83e","40-<50","0.85-<1.15","80-<98","3.0-<3.4","NA","3.0-<3.4 (110)")
str_extract(V, "((?<=\\<)\\d\\.?\\d+|NA)") %>% 
      as.numeric()

[1]  7.35 32.00 83.00 50.00  1.15 98.00  3.40    NA  3.40
```